# Appending a php variable to html

Tags: php, ajax, comments

I am developing a comment box for my website. When a message is posted on the website and another user comes and wants to reply, the previous message message should display below it.

I am showing the message in a `<ul>`. Each UL child (which is LI), contains a table that shows the message.

**Link to image**

[Comments Showing](http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/122.jpg)

Suppose these are the comments showing:

> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Comment One By David
>
> ################################################################ Reply of David
>   
>   ########################## Another Reply of David
>
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Comment Two By Jhon

My messages are showing using AJAX and PHP.

An AJAX script sends data, which goes to a PHP script and then after verification goes to a database and in the mean time it's also updated on the screen.

My problem is that if I want to reply to a message at the end, or want to add a new message it works fine, but when I want to reply to a message which is previously added I do not know how to put it in between html code.

**Problem**

Suppose I want to reply to "David", when I submit the comment it goes below the last message not between the messages.

**HTML**

```
           <div id="add-comment" title="Comment">
    <ol  class="timeline" id="update">                                  
        <?
        $retrieve = $con->select1("*", "`comments`", "page_id=" . $page_id);
        $confirm_author = 0;            
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve)) {
            echo'<table class="shw-comment" id="show-comment-table" ><tbody><tr>';
            $name = $con->verify_author($row['name'], $row['email'], $row['website']);                
            echo'<td align="left" colspan="9" id="name-td">' . $name;
            $niceDay = $con->perfect_date_format($row['date_and_time']);
            echo'<div align="right" id="comment-date">' . $niceDay . '</div></td></tr><tr>';
            echo'<td align="left" id="user-icon-td">';
            if ($name == "Author") {
                echo '<div class="author" id="user-icon"></div>';
            } else {
                $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($row['email'])));
                $default_usr = urlencode('http://localhost/king-of-developers/images/user-icon.png');
                echo "<div class=\"default-user\" id=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash.'.jpg?s=45&d=$default_usr'\"  /></div>";
            }
            echo '</td>';
            echo'<td colspan="8" id="user-comments-td" valign="top">' . $row['user_comments'] . '</td>';
            echo'</tr><tr>';
            echo'<td align="right" colspan="9" id="reply-td"><input type="button" class="reply" name="reply" value="reply" title="reply"/></td>';
            echo'<tr>
                    <td align="left" colspan="9">
                    <input id="comment-id' . $row['id'] . '" type="hidden" value="' . $row['id'] . '"/>';
            echo'</tr>';
            echo'</tbody></table></li>';
            if($row['respond'] == 1){
                $retrieve2 = $con->select1("*", "`comment_respond`", "comment_id=" . $row['id']);                    
                $confirm_author = 0;
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve2)) {
                    echo'<table class="shw-comment" id="comment-reply" ><tbody><tr>';
                    $name = $con->verify_author($row2['name'], $row2['email'], $row2['website']);
                    echo'<td align="left" colspan="9" id="name-td">' . $name;
                    $niceDay = $con->perfect_date_format($row2['date_and_time']);
                    echo'<div align="right" id="comment-date">' . $niceDay . '</div></td></tr><tr>';
                    echo'<td align="left" id="user-icon-td">';
                    if ($name == "Author") {
                        echo '<div class="author" id="user-icon"></div>';
                    } else {
                        $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($row2['email'])));
                        $default_usr = urlencode('http://localhost/king-of-developers/images/user-icon.png');
                        echo "<div class=\"default-user\" id=\"user-icon\"><img src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash.'.jpg?s=45&d=$default_usr'\"  /></div>";        
                    }
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo'<td colspan="8" id="user-comments-td" valign="top">' . $row2['user_comments'] . '</td>';
                    echo'</tr><tr>';
                    echo'<td align="right" colspan="9" id="reply-td"><input type="button" class="reply" name="reply" value="reply" title="reply"/></td>';
                    echo'<tr>
                            <td align="left" colspan="9">
                            <input id="comment-id' . $row['id'] . '" type="hidden" value="' . $row['id'] . '"/>';
                    echo'</tr>';
                    echo'</tbody></table></li>';
                }    
            }
        }    
        ?>
    </ol>
```

**Ajax code**

```
                        $(".submit-comment").click(function(){
    var a="",b=0;
    var n=$("#your-name").val();
    var e=$("#your-email").val();
    var w=$("#your-website").val();
    var c=$("#comments").val();
    var pg=$("#page-no").val();
    var rp=$("#respond").val();
    var ch=$("[name=recaptcha_challenge_field]").val();
    var re=$("[name=recaptcha_response_field]").val();
    var confirmAuthor=0;
    n=$.trim(n);
    e=$.trim(e);
    w=$.trim(w);
    c=$.trim(c);
    var h="name="+n+"&email="+e+"&web="+w+"&comment="+c+"&challenge="+ch+"&response="+re+"&respond="+rp+"&page_id="+pg;
    document.getElementById("recaptcha_reload_btn").click();
    if(n==""||e==""||c==""||$.trim(re)==""){
        a+="\n Please Write Your 'Name' , 'Email' , 'Comments' and 'Captcha' Before   Submiting. ";
        b++;
    }else{
        var i=/[-_@'$&`~;?%^)*(#!0-9]/;
        var temp=n;
        temp.toLowerCase();
        if(temp=="author"){
            a+="\nInvalid User Name";
            b++;
        }
        if(i.test(n)){
            a+="\nPlease Write a Correct Name ! ";
            b++;
        }
        i=/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/;
        if(!i.test(e)){
            a+="\nPlease Write Valid Email Address ! ";
            b++;
        }
    }
    if(b>=1){
        alert(a);
    }
    if(b==0){
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"admin/include/ajax-comments.php",
            data:h,
            cache:false,
            success:function(a){
                $("ol#update").append(a);
                $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                document.getElementById("your-email").value="";
                document.getElementById("your-name").value="";
                document.getElementById("your-website").value="";
                document.getElementById("comments").value="";
                document.getElementById("respond").value="";
                $("#recaptcha_reload_btn").click();
                $("#your-name").focus();
                $("#flash").hide();                    
            }
        })
    }
    return false;
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
                    <?php
                require_once('recaptchalib.php');
                $privatekey = "64444444444444";
                $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],  $_POST["challenge"], $_POST["response"]);
                 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                 //What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
                 die("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .   
                "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
                 } 
                else 
                {
                   // Your code here to handle a successful verification
                   require_once '../config.php';
                   $con = new config();
                  if ($_POST) {
                  $name = $_POST['name'];
                  $email = $_POST['email'];
                  $web = $_POST['web'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $respond = $_POST['respond'];
    $page = $_POST['page_id'];
    $name = $con->clean_input($name);
    $email = $con->clean_input($email);
    $web = $con->clean_input($web);
    $comment = $con->clean_input($comment);
    $name = $con->sanitizeHTML($name);
    $email = $con->sanitizeHTML($email);
    $web = $con->sanitizeHTML($web);
    $comment = $con->sanitizeHTML($comment);
    $con->validateNull($name, "Please Enter Your Name ");
    $con->validateEmail($email, "Please Enter Your Valid Email");
    $con->validateNull($comment, "Please Don't Leave Empty Comments");
    if ($con->errorCounter == 0) {
        $name = ucwords(strtolower($name));
        $comment = ucfirst(strtolower($comment));            
        $con->setTime_zone();
        $comment_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        $comment_time = $con->perfect_date_format($comment_time);
        $ip = $con->getIP();            
        if ($respond >= 1) {
            $col[0] = "comment_id";
            $col[1] = "name";
            $col[2] = "email";
            $col[3] = "website";
            $col[4] = "user_comments";
            $col[5] = "user_ip";
            $col[6] = "date_and_time";
            $data[0] = "'" . $respond . "'";
            $data[1] = "'" . $name . "'";
            $data[2] = "'" . $email . "'";
            $data[3] = "'" . $web . "'";
            $data[4] = "'" . $comment . "'";
            $data[5] = "'" . $ip . "'";
            $data[6] = "'" . $comment_time . "'";
            $con->insert("`comment_respond`", $col, $data);
            $con->update("`comments`", "`respond`= 1","`id`='".$respond."'");                
        }
        if ($respond == 0) {
            $col[0] = "page_id";
            $col[1] = "respond";
            $col[2] = "name";
            $col[3] = "email";
            $col[4] = "website";
            $col[5] = "user_comments";
            $col[6] = "user_ip";
            $col[7] = "date_and_time";
            $data[0] = "'" . $page . "'";
            $data[1] = "'" . $respond . "'";
            $data[2] = "'" . $name . "'";
            $data[3] = "'" . $email . "'";
            $data[4] = "'" . $web . "'";
            $data[5] = "'" . $comment . "'";
            $data[6] = "'" . $ip . "'";
            $data[7] = "'" . $comment_time . "'";
            $con->insert("`comments`", $col, $data);                
            $comment_id = mysql_insert_id();
        }
    } else {
        $arraysize = count($con->errorMsg);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $arraysize; $i++) {
            echo $con->errorMsg[$i] . "<br>";
        }
    }
    $confirm_author = 0;
    $con->close_connection();
   }
}
?>
     <li>
              <?php
               if ($respond >= 1){
               echo '<table class="shw-comment" id="comment-reply">';
              }
              if ($respond == 0){
                  echo '<table class="shw-comment" id="show-comment-table">';
              }
             ?>    
             <tbody>
                <?
                    $name = $con->verify_author($name, $email, $web);
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="9" id="name-td">
                    <? echo $name; ?>
                <div align="right" id="comment-date">
                <? echo $comment_time; ?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                                
            <td align="left" id="user-icon-td">
                <?
                if ($name == "Author") {
                    echo '<div class="author" id="user-icon"></div>';
                } else {
                    $hash = md5(strtolower(trim($email)));
                    $def_usr = urlencode('http://www.kingofdevelopers.com/images/user-icon.jpg');
                    echo "<div class='default-user' id=\"user-icon\"><img     src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/$hash.'.jpg?s=45&d=$def_usr'\"  /></div>";
                }
                ?>               
            </td>
            <td  colspan="8" id="user-comments-td" valign="top">
            <? echo $comment; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="9" id="reply-td">
                <input type="button" class="reply" name="reply" value="reply"  title="reply" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="9">
                <?
                    if($respond >= 1){
                        $conct ='comment-id'.$respond;
                        echo "<input id='$conct' type='hidden' value=''/>";
                    }
                    if($respond == 0){
                        $conct ='comment-id'.$comment_id;
                        echo "<input id='$conct' type='hidden' value=''/>";
                    }    
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you have an image that is required to explain your question, you can always host it at an external image provider and include a link in your question.

Comment: My eyes are burning! You need to get out of the habit of echoing html in php. It is rarely necessary. Your code would be infinitely more readable if you do like so: <?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($retriv2)): ?><table>...</table><?php endwhile; ?>

Answer (score 2):

If one were to tag each comment with a unique ID, then reference this ID in your AJAX response.

Once the response is received simply find the matching ID and insert HTML comment snippet accordingly.

Comment: I'm plussing this because the general idea is correct but obviously this answer would or could have been much more useful if the question provided the actual ajax code and html to show you how to append the new comment.

Comment: @KaiQing +1 to you for the word "plussing" :D. Also, I agree with what you say